# Ну конечно туалет. Ставить ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Вечером часов в 18-19 перед поездкой ищут, как вы думаете что? Ну конечно туалет. Ставится ли запятые, является ли «конечно» вводным?

Comment: Стоило бы обсудить постановку запятых в первом предложении тоже. Я бы выделил "часов в 18-19" запятыми.

Comment: Трудно представить себе контекст, который оправдывал бы такое количество деталей. Перед поездкой ищут что? Тулет. Почему именно вечером? И почему именно часов в 18-19? – М_Г 11 минут назад

Comment: это письмо возмущенного читателя в газету об отсутствии туалета на одной из крымских автостанций.... 18-19 часов - пик пассажирского потока....

Comment: Я примерно так и думал. Конечно, отсутствии туалета в час пик - хуже, чем отсутвие его в другое время :) . Можно было бы выразить эту мысль более понятно - но редакторская правка должна быть минимальной...

Answer (score 3):

Из словаря:

**КОНЕЧНО**. **I. частица**. Употр. при выражении согласия, подтверждения сказанного; да, разумеется. Есть будешь? - К.! Вы говорите по-английски? - К.! II. **вводн. сл.** Разумеется, несомненно. К., привычка много значит. Вы, к., к нам придёте?

Правила позволяют не обособлять "конечно" только  **в ответной реплике**, но здесь пропущенный вопрос **подразумевается**: Ищут, как вы думаете, что? ― Туалет? ― **Ну конечно туалет.**

Пример: Ты же такая не одна? - **Ну конечно же не одна.**. Нас тут полно таких, о малыше мечтающих:

Answer (score 1):

***В данном случае, слово "конечно" является не вводным, а усилительным***: оно подчеркивает эффект уверенного тона автора. Является синонимом слова "точно", еще его можно заменить словом "несомненно", "однозначно", "бесспорно" и т. д. ***Запятые до и после "конечно" в этом случае не ставятся***.